# How to make a list of functions in python?

Tags: python, function, pointers

I tried to achieve something like this

```
list1 = [lambda x: x+0, lambda x: x+1]
```

by doing this

```
list2 = [lambda x: x+n for n in range(2)]
```

But it doesn't work! (Why not?)
How do I create a list of functions programmatically?

Comment: because lambda binds `n` to the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is reassigned by the for expression, so after the for expression is completed both will see value of `n` being 1.

More typical example of this problem can be visible without list expression:

```
list3 = []
for n in range(2):
    def f(x):
        return x + n
    list3.append(f)
```

Here also all created function objects will refer to the same variable `n` and it will be assigned value 1 and both function objects will work as `lambda x: x + 1`.

You can deal with it by creating additional scope with a variable for each created function:

```
a = [(lambda n: lambda x: x+n)(n) for n in range(2)]
```

Comment: Indeed, this was my first try, and then I figured that lambdas might work, except not...